# In season 1 of The Walking Dead, why does Jenner whisper it to Rick

Tags: the-walking-dead

I don't get why Jenner felt the need to whisper

> we're all infected

to Rick. He could have flat out told him. I don't understand his secrecy, I know it was early days of the apocalypse  but he was going to kill himself. He clearly stopped caring and it's not a secret worth keeping. It shouldn't have mattered, but I want to know why it did.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a secret worth keeping. The going assumption was that the living would not turn into walkers unless they died of a bite from a walker. Many in Rick's group wanted to avoid that fate. The fear was that some people might just give up if they found out that there was no way to avoid becoming a walker eventually, and this did happen once the secret got out.

Answer (score 0):

I get why you would say it wasn't worth keeping. Because it came from Jenner's point of view, at the time he was trying to make them understand why they should all want to kill themselves along with him in the decontamination.

If Jenner was trying to argue his point, then it made sense for him to have told all of them to try and reason with him and get there is no hope because everybody is infected. For Jenner it shouldn't have mattered and he should have just said it, he had given up and was trying to get the group to understand why, he should have told them all.

The only reason I can get is because the writers wanted a hook for viewers tbh and back in the day, season 1, nobody knew.